# My picker is not actually selecting values?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5, picker

So I have a picker that pops up instead of the keyboard, however it does not change values when you scroll to different points on the picker. I test this by having an alert show what age was selected, and it never changes from the first option. I would think the alert is broken, but the blue selector outline over the currently selected option in the picker is not showing up either. Here is the code for both the picker and the alert:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]        initWithObjects:@"18-29",@"30-39",@"40-49",@"50-59",@"60+",nil];
    self.pickerData = array;
}

-(IBAction)UITextFieldEditingDidBegin
{

    UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] 
                            initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 244, 320, 270)];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:picker];
    [picker release];

}

-(IBAction)donePressed
{

NSInteger row = [agePicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
NSString *selected = [pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
NSString *title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                   @"You selected %@!", selected];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                               message : @"Thank you for choosing."
                                               delegate:nil
                                     cancelButtonTitle :@"Okay!"             
                                     otherButtonTitles :nil];
[alert show];
[agePicker resignFirstResponder];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [pickerData count];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
        titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
       forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
    return[pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Comment: I'm also having trouble dismissing the picker as well if anyone wants to shed some light on that. If you can't tell I am really new to Xcode (and do not know much about programming in general)

Comment: Like any other UIView you can animate its alpha or frame position, I dont think it has a built-in hide/show mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit,
to help dismiss your picker,
make it an instance var, declare your picker in the interface,

MyClass.h

```
@interface MyClass:UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>{
UIPickerView *picker
}
```

MyClass.m

```
@interface MyClass()
property (nonatomic, retain) *selectedVal; //make it a NSString
@end



-(IBAction)UITextFieldEditingDidBegin
{

    picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] 
                            initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 244, 320, 270)];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:picker];
    //[picker release]; //Place your picker release in the dealloc method

}
```

You have to implement the delegate for the picker,

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
 self.selectedVal = [pickerData objectAtIndex:row]
NSLog(@"Selected option: %@. ", self.selectedVal );
}
```

Then on your done button, you have the selected val in your property for use

```
-(IBAction)donePressed
{


NSString *title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                   @"You selected %@!", self.selectedVal];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                               message : @"Thank you for choosing."
                                               delegate:nil
                                     cancelButtonTitle :@"Okay!"             
                                     otherButtonTitles :nil];
[alert show];
[alert release]; //I noticed you release the picker, so not using ARC, so release             alert!!
[picker resignFirstResponder];

 //after done, remove the picker from the view
 [picker removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I do have one more question if you'd be willing to answer it, even though everything does work. The picker still does not have a selector bar hovering over the currently selected value, although it does recognize the one in the middle as the currently selected value. Do you know why it is not showing or how to make it appear?